# react-router v2 - replace in onEnter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, server-rendering

In my app I'm using react-router v2 - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

I have problem with redirect in `onEnter`:

**some component**

```
static async onEnter({ flux }, nextState, replace, callback) {
    const token = flux.getStore('auth').getAccessToken();
    if (!token) {
        replace('/login');
        return callback();
    }
}
```

I'm using server-side rendering and have used this guide - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md#async-routes as it says I need to use `match` on client too:

**client.js**

```
RouterMatch({history: browserHistory, routes: patchedRouteHooks(routes)}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    // renderProps are `undefined` when replace from onEnter hook
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router {...renderProps} createElement={passFluxToComponent} />,
        mountNode,
    );
});
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={AppHandler}>
        <Route path="/" component={AuthHandler}>
            <Route path="login(/)" component={LoginFormHandler} />
            <Route path="signup(/)" component={SignupFormHandler} />
            <Route path="resetpassword(/)" component={ResetPasswordFormHandler} />
            <Route path="changepassword(/)" component={ChangePasswordFormHandler} />
            <Route path="logout(/)" component={LogoutHandler} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/" component={AppLayoutHandler}>
            <Route path="/" component={EnsureAuthHandler}>
                <Route path="me/favorites(/)" component={FavoritePropertiesHandler} />
                <Route path="me/settings(/)" component={UserSettingsHandler} />
                <Route path="dashboard(/)(:status)(/)" component={DashboardFlowHandler} />
                <IndexRoute component={DashboardFlowHandler} />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/s(/)" component={SearchResultsHandler} />
            <Route path="/user/:id(/)" component={UserDetailsHandler} />
            <IndexRoute component={EnsureAuthHandler} />
        </Route>

        <IndexRoute component={AppLayoutHandler} />
    </Route>
);

export default routes
```

**patchRouteHooks.js**

```
function patchRouteHooks (Route, patchData = {}) {
    const { props: { children, component } } = Route;

    function _patchChildren (children) {
        if (Array.isArray(children)) {
            return React.Children.map(children, ChildRoute => patchRouteHooks(ChildRoute, patchData));
        } else {
            return patchRouteHooks(children, patchData);
        }
    }

    return {
        ...Route,
        props: {
            ...Route.props,
            onEnter: component && component.onEnter && function (...args) {
                component.onEnter.call(null, patchData, ...args);
            },
            onLeave: component && component.onLeave && function (...args) {
                component.onLeave.call(null, patchData, ...args);
            },
            children: children ? _patchChildren(children) : null
        }
    };
}

export default patchRouteHooks;
```

After replace in onEnter I receive renderProps as `undefined` which results in warnings in console and broken app:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`.

Comment: Can you post what you have in routes.js? (if you are using universal rendering, it's the shared routes for both client and server)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, renderProps are `undefined`.

Instead of passing renderProps, I did something that would roughly be in your case :
`ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes ={patchedRouteHooks(routes)} createElement={passFluxToComponent} />,
        mountNode,
    );`

Not able to fully understand what match is doing asynchronously, and having a perfectly functional app (with server rendering) without it, I just stopped using it :)

You can keep your current implementation (with match) and wrap your fallback render in a

`if (redirectLocation) {
   ...my proposition
} else {
   ...your implementation
}`